# Translation Resources: Star/Constellation Names

Tags: translation, resources

What resources are available for translations (well English equivalents) of Chinese **星官** (constellations) **星名** (stars)?

For example:

**宦者**

> 3 星官名。

How -or- where can I find the English equivalent for this constellation?

**皇位**

> 2 指星名。

How -or- where can I find the English equivalent for this constellation?

An (extremely comprehensive) star/constellation dictionary would be awesome.

What resources are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[中西星名对照表 on wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E8%A5%BF%E6%98%9F%E5%90%8D%E5%B0%8D%E7%85%A7%E8%A1%A8) has ~1000 star names and is good enough for common astrophiles.

I haven't read the book but it is said [《中西对照·恒星图表1950.0》](http://book.douban.com/subject/25760319/) has more than 3000 star names, which might be the extremely comprehensive dictionary you're looking for.